# Wordpress Contact Form 7 (CF7) execute jQuery after submitting but before mail is sent

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 form and a piece of jQuery code. I am using the jQuery already in the form, there it works well. Nevertheless, I also want to use it in the mail that is transmitted. I suppose I could use wpcf7_before_send_mail. But this is PHP, my variable is created dynamically using jQuery. So it does not fit.

HTML in the form:

```
<span class="myplaceholder">MY PLACEHOLDER</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".myplaceholder").text(myvariable);
```

Now I also need to run the jQuery on the email. It should be something like that:

1. click on "submit"
2. create an email
3. run jquery on that email created and substitute myplaceholder with the value of the dynamically created variable.
4. Submit email.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Raphael

Comment: you cannot run jquery on the email.  The email is created on the back-end.  So yuo can only run PHP code to modify the email before it is sent

Comment: use hidden input type and set the value.  This gets passed to the email.

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden input and set the value using jQuery.

In your contact form:

`[hidden your-var-name id:myplaceholder]`

Your script :

`$("#myplaceholder").val(myvariable);`

In your email on CF7 - no need to use hooks...

`[your-var-name]`